# Why does clicking on a button that's not marked as submit cause a form to be submitted?

Tags: javascript

Here's my form. The problem is when I click on the second button it logs me off

```
<form action="/Account/LogOff"
      id="logoutForm"
      method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button class="small" type="submit" >Logout</button>
    <button id="theme" onclick="setThemeColor(this)">#</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thats just the way `button` works.

Answer (score 6):

Because the default type for a button is `submit`.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

For this reason you would have to prevent this behavior either through js, or by setting its type to `button`

```
<button id="theme" onclick="setThemeColor(this)" type="button">#</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful but jeez, buttons didn't behave like this in the old days, surely...

Answer (score 4):

You can cancel the default event of the element, which is submit in this case, by returning false;

```
<button id="theme" onclick="setThemeColor(this); return false;">#</button>
```

**Addition:**

If the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value, button will behave as a submit. Since you `have not specified type attribute` to your button, it is behaving like a submit.

Comment: True, but the question is "why does it happen?" Not "How can I stop it?" (Though the latter is implicit).

Comment: @DavidThomas: default event is submit which is cancelling by returning false. I will update the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

It will not happen if you specify button using `input` tag. Strange but true.

Eg:

```
 <input type="button" id="theme" onclick="setThemeColor(this)" />
```

Check the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kjk4y/